# How can I convert a kotlin Map<String, String?> to Map<String, String> in a clear way?

Tags: kotlin

I'd like to find the clearest and most elegant way to convert a `Map<String, String?>` to a `Map<String, String>`, filtering out the pairs with `null` values.

I have a contrived solution below, but I don't like how I have to do an unsafe `!!`.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
fun Map<String, String?>.filterNonNull() = this
            .filter { it.value != null }
            .map { it.key to it.value!! }
            .toMap()
```

Comment: I'd argue that there is nothing bad about `!!` in this particular situation: it's pretty simple function, and it's clear that there is no NPE. So I like your solution (it can be simplified/optimized by using https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-values.html)

Comment: if you've already filtered out all the null results then I don't see how your !! is unsafe

Comment: It's actually much more questionable that you have `Map<..., ...?>` in the first place. When I write `your_map[k]` and receive `null`, I would usually expect it to means that the key is not present in the map. Maybe it's possible to avoid creating such map at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mapNotNull` serves as a combination of `map` and `filter`, but returns a `List` and not the `Map` you want so

```
fun <K, V> Map<K, V?>.filterNonNull(): Map<K, V> = 
    this.mapNotNull { 
        (key, value) -> if (value == null) null else Pair(key, value) 
    }.toMap()
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the discussion [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-4734#focus=streamItem-27-2921931.0-0) you can also use something like this:

```
fun <K, V> Map<K, V?>.filterNotNullValues(): Map<K, V> =
    mutableMapOf<K, V>().apply { 
        for ((k, v) in this@filterNotNullValues) if (v != null) put(k, v) 
    }
```